# JavaScript - check for value in json

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure. It is result of JSON.parse:

```
[{"model": "game.bowlinggame", "pk": 2587, "fields": {"Frame": 1, "FrameRow": 1, "Result": 10, "StrikeSpare": 2, "StrikeSpareInfo": "X", "Time": "2017-10-15T17:20:53.994Z", "GameId": 42, "StateOfGame": 1}}, {"model": "game.bowlinggame", "pk": 2588, "fields": {"Frame": 1, "FrameRow": 2, "Result": null, "StrikeSpare": null, "StrikeSpareInfo": null, "Time": "2017-10-15T17:20:53.996Z", "GameId": 42, "StateOfGame": 1}}]
```

I want to check if the value of 'StateOfGame' == 2. I tried this but It's wrong:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < game_frame.length; i++) {
            var obj = game_frame[i];
            for (var key in obj){
                console.log(key['fields']['StateOfGame']);
                if (i['fields']['StateOfGame'] == 2){
                    do_something;
              }   
            }
        }
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: `obj.fields.StateOfGame == 2`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do something while `StateOfGame == 2`, you can do something like this:

```
// using lodash each
_.each(jsonData,data => {
  if(data.fields.StateOfGame === 2){
   // do something
  }
});
// using javascript forEach
jsonData.forEach(data => { 
    if(data.fields.StateOfGame === 2){
        //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` method of array and filter that particular value, please find below the code.

***Note: I have modified the second array object to have `StateOfGame` property to be `2`***

```js
var array = [{
  "model": "game.bowlinggame",
  "pk": 2587,
  "fields": {
    "Frame": 1,
    "FrameRow": 1,
    "Result": 10,
    "StrikeSpare": 2,
    "StrikeSpareInfo": "X",
    "Time": "2017-10-15T17:20:53.994Z",
    "GameId": 42,
    "StateOfGame": 1
  }
}, {
  "model": "game.bowlinggame",
  "pk": 2588,
  "fields": {
    "Frame": 1,
    "FrameRow": 2,
    "Result": null,
    "StrikeSpare": null,
    "StrikeSpareInfo": null,
    "Time": "2017-10-15T17:20:53.996Z",
    "GameId": 42,
    "StateOfGame": 2
  }
}];

var output = array.filter(function(x) {
  return x.fields.StateOfGame === 2;
});
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console {
  height: 100%;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @sretko Does this answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

In your original JSON structure, none of your games has a `StateOfGame` of 2. I tweaked it and shortened your code a bit:

```js
const data = [{"model": "game.bowlinggame", "pk": 2587, "fields": {"Frame": 1, "FrameRow": 1, "Result": 10, "StrikeSpare": 2, "StrikeSpareInfo": "X", "Time": "2017-10-15T17:20:53.994Z", "GameId": 42, "StateOfGame": 1}}, {"model": "game.bowlinggame", "pk": 2588, "fields": {"Frame": 1, "FrameRow": 2, "Result": null, "StrikeSpare": null, "StrikeSpareInfo": null, "Time": "2017-10-15T17:20:53.996Z", "GameId": 42, "StateOfGame": 2}}];

const filtered = data.filter( item => {
  return item.fields && item.fields.StateOfGame === 2;
} );
console.log( filtered );
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is sometimes usefull to loop through an object, you generally do not need to.

```
for (var i = 0; i < game_frame.length; i++) {
   if(game_frame[i]['fields']['StateOfGame'] == 2){
       do_something;
   }  
}
```

you can (and the circumstances allowing, should) access object members by their names instead of looping through the object.

If you absolutely must loop through an object (there are some instances where that is usefull, this one is not) you would need to do something like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < game_frame.length; i++) {
   for(var field in game_frame[i]['fields']){
      if(field == 'StateOfGame' && game_frame[i]['fields'][field] == 2){
       do_something;
      }
   }  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the inner loop.

Each element of the  array is an object that has a property `fields` which is an object with property `StateOfGame`

```
 for (var i = 0; i < game_frame.length; i++) {
     if(game_frame[i].fields.StateOfGame === 2){
         do_something();
     }
 }
```